# Flex checkbox itemrenderer in datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, flex3

in my flex application im using a datagrid which has three coloumns
first column is for checkbox as itemRenderer and 
other two columns are editable.

my requirement is

now when i fetch some data from DB the datas will be populated in datagrid,

1.after populating datas, first column should be disabled in all rows
2.if i click second or third column in a row for editing.. the checkbox in first column corresponding row should be enabled and checkbox should be ready for check and uncheck..

how can i do this 
here's my code

```
<mx:DataGrid x="46" y="135" dataProvider="{DetailsProvider}" width="836" height="349">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Select" dataField="isSelect" itemRenderer="com.components.checkbox"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="First Name" dataField="fname"/>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Second Name" dataField="sname"/></mx:columns></mx:DataGrid>
```

I hope this details is enough to understand my question
Any idea for this.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I am providing you the sample code that i have created that uses ItemRenderer and ItemEditor both in a single DataGrid you just need to create a new mxml component that is name d ComNS and ComCB. Just create that i am givng you the sample code.

Code for main mxml Appication

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" horizontalAlign="center" 
verticalAlign="middle" height="100%" width="100%">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var arr:Array = new Array({isSelected:true,label:'ABC',score:'78',name:'ABC'},
                                         {isSelected:true,label:'DEF',score:'50',name:'DEF'},
                                         {isSelected:false,label:'GHI',score:'70',name:'GHI'},
                                         {isSelected:false,label:'JKL',score:'80',name:'JKL'},
                                         {isSelected:true,label:'TRE',score:'50',name:'MNO'});

        public function dgCLG_dataChange():void
        {

        }

        public function dgCLG_change():void
        {

        }

        public function btnSubmit_click():void
        {
            dgCopy.dataProvider = dgCLG.dataProvider;
        }

    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:VBox height="100%" width="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">
    <mx:DataGrid id="dgCLG" dataProvider="{arr}" editable="true" dataChange="{dgCLG_dataChange();}" change="{dgCLG_change();}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="" dataField="isSelected">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <mx:Component>
                        <mx:Box horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" height="100%" width="100%">
                            <mx:Script>
                                <![CDATA[
                                    override public function set data(value:Object):void
                                    {
                                        if(value != null)
                                        {
                                            super.data = value;
                                            var temp:Object = value as Object;
                                            chb.selected = temp.isSelected;
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]]>
                            </mx:Script>
                            <mx:CheckBox id="chb"/>
                        </mx:Box>
                    </mx:Component>                     
                </mx:itemRenderer>
            </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Label" dataField="label" editable="false">

            </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Marks" dataField="score" editable="true" itemEditor="ComNS" editorDataField="value">

            </mx:DataGridColumn>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Person" itemEditor="ComCB" editorDataField="value" editable="true">

            </mx:DataGridColumn>
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>  

    <mx:Button id="btnSubmit" label="Click" click="{btnSubmit_click();}" />

    <mx:DataGrid id="dgCopy" editable="false">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="CopyLabel" dataField="label" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="CopyMarks" dataField="score" />
            <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="CopyPerson" dataField="name" />
        </mx:columns>
    </mx:DataGrid>
</mx:VBox>

</mx:Application>
```

Code for ComNS.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:NumericStepper xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" minimum="0" maximum="100">

</mx:NumericStepper>
```

Code for ComCB.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:ComboBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" dataProvider="{arr}" selectedIndex="1" creationComplete="{c_complete();}" >
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        public var arr:Array = new Array({label:'ABC'},{label:'DEF'},{label:'GHI'},{label:'JKL'},{label:'MNO'})

        public function c_complete():void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i].label == parentDocument.dgCLG.selectedItem.name)
                {
                    this.selectedItem = arr[i];
                }
            }   
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
</mx:ComboBox>
```

If any query just comment on my answer....

Answer (score 0):

If you implement IDropInListItemRenderer, your renderer will be passed a BaseListData object which, among other things, will contain a reference to the DataGrid. With that reference to the DataGrid, you can compare its selectedItem to the data object for that renderer to enable or disable the check box.

Note that Checkbox is supposed to already implement this Interface, so in theory you should just be able to use it with a couple of tweaks. However, it is not implemented properly by Adobe.  Check the comments to this page in the online help for how to fix that http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=celleditor_4.html .